# Can we add where clause into placeholders of prepared statements

Tags: java, jdbc

Can we add query commands like 'where' in placeholder strings in prepared statement. For example:

```
String name = "1";
String sql = "select * from Emp ?";
PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement(sql);  
String namefake="where Emp_id="+name;
stmt.setString(1, namefake); 
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

If not, are there any ways to perform sql injections in prepared statements.

Comment: why not try the code you wrote? it will show you the result

Comment: No, you can't. Only column values are allowed.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Obviously I tried the code. But I am still an amateur programmer. Just wanted to know if there were any other methods to bypass a prepared Statement jdbc code. I am sorry that I didnt frame my question properly:(.